CustomStateParameters available in different components, .NET 8
I have a class with some currentstate parameters (instead of session variables)
In program.cs:
builder.Services.AddScoped<CurrentState>();    

Can I inject this CurrentState and read / update parameters at runtime?
When I tried this every component that inject this with @inject CurrentState currentState, every currentState = null and get a new hashcode (currentState.GetHashCode())
I've read an article somewhere that you can do this but can't find it again. Is it totally wrong and I must use sessions or is there a way to use this ang get same instance of CurrentState in all components?
Found an article similiar : https://wellsb.com/csharp/aspnet/blazor-singleton-pass-data-between-pages#google_vignette
I use serverside so can't use .Singleton. But it seams like I get a completely new instance on every injection?
Maybe I can use cascadingparameters in Routes.razor?
CustomStateSevice
class CustomStateService 
{
  public User UserItem {get;set}  // There is a class with Userdata
  public int SomeIntData {get;set;
}

Program.cs
builder.Services.AddScoped<CustomStateService>();    
builder.Services.AddScoped<UserInitializationService>();

    builder.Services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
    {
        options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
        {
            OnTokenValidated = async ctx =>
            {
                var userState = ctx.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<CustomStateService>();
                var userInitializationService = ctx.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<UserInitializationService>();

                var user = ctx.Principal;
                await userInitializationService.InitializeUserAsync(user);
            }
        };
    });

UserInitializationService
public class UserInitializationService
{
    private readonly CustomStateService _customState;
    private readonly IUserRepository _userRepository;

    public UserInitializationService(CustomStateService customStateService, IUserRepository userRepository)
    {
        _customState = customStateService;
        _userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    public async Task InitializeUserAsync(ClaimsPrincipal user)
    {
        if (user.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            var tempUser = new User
            {
                AdId = user.FindFirst("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier").Value,
                Email = user.Identity.Name,
                Name = user.FindFirst("name").Value,
                LatestActivty = DateTime.Now
            };

            _customState.UserItem = await _userRepository.CheckUser(tempUser);

        }
        else
        {
            _customState.UserItem = null;
        }
    }
}

And in component
@inject CustomStateService _csService

@code{
...
    User userItem = _csService.UserItem;
...

Now every parameter in userItem is null.
Maybe this only works in webassembly where you can use .AddSingleton();  ?
Maybe it's better to set my CustomStateService value in Routes.cs and then distribute this as a CascadingParameter?

What do you mean by currentState=null. The current state is null when accessing it? How is it related to the CustomTokenProvider?

Forget about CustomTokenProvider, I read an article about share data between pages/components and one example was about saving token for make it easy to use on different places.
Let's say user logg in, I run some code after user logged in that I've setup in program.cs and get data from SQL server that I will use, maybe userspecific data.  for example CurrentState.User.Id = xxx.   I set value, then I will use this value on other component  there I inject CurrentState...  But in that other component CurrentState.User.Id is null and not xxx.

Found an article similiar to what I wan't to do, link above.

Please share the relevant code of your state management service CurrentState.cs

Update question above with examplecode what I try to achieve.

This should work, since the Scoped service should be new for every new circuit (connected user), but same in that same circuit. Maybe it doesn't go through the InitializeUserAsync at all? Or maybe the ctx.HttpContext.RequestService is doing something differently..

What Render mode are you using and where are you setting interactivity?  My guess is that you can achieve what you want - get some extra user data - through a custom AuthenticationStateProvider.  You can then add this to your CustomStateService .  At the moment I'm a little confused as a HttpContext in only available in SSR pages.  Any service constructed in SSR isn't persisted to the Blazor SPA.

I test some different things. I have override my Savechangesasync in dbcontext, there I have inject CustomStateService to get current userid, there it works. But not when I inject in a razor page/component. But If I inject in Router.cs and then pass my CustomStateObject as Cascading parameter I can get data that way. But strange that I can use inject in some situations and get data but not everywhere.

@MrCakaShaunCurtis  rendermode = InteractiveServer

Interactivity - Global or Per Page/Component [it's important]?  Once you answer that I'll have a good look at your code.

@MrCakaShaunCurtis it's global setting.

Yes in my test the state is empty when you navigate to a new page everytime. Cascading parameters will do but what is the design , why no session choices as the cascading parameter is not more commonly applied in this situation.
